# How can I use fetch to call an API in script lab?

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm trying to use the fetch function to call an API in script lab using the code of a youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VL1m9lPYA7I -video
https://gist.github.com/hobru/e25ce0f58403c1b8d31a443b2b2adfdb -code to import

It doesn't seem to recognize any of the methods that fetch uses (Headers, Request), nor the fetch function itself.

This is the error the code produces:

"   ▶ReferenceError {description: "'Request' is undefined", number: -2146823279, stack: "ReferenceError: 'Request' is undefinedat Anonymous function (https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/:113:21)at step [...]

description: "'Request' is undefined"

message: "'Request' is undefined"

number: -2146823279

stack: "ReferenceError: 'Request' is undefinedat Anonymous function

▶**proto**: ReferenceError"

Sorry, I can't post the complete error with so many webpages links.

[Image of error][1]

How can I sort this out?

Thanks

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPTPR.png -image

Comment: I just have a tried on the gist, it works as expected, it's as same as the video. could you please share your screenshot of the error information? what's the version of your excel?

Comment: Mine it's Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.12624.20424) 64 bits. Apparently a different user had the same problem and commented on Github right below where the code is. The error is : ReferenceError {description: "'Headers' is undefined", number: -2146823279, stack: "ReferenceError: 'Headers' is undefinedat Anonymous function (https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/:112:21)at step (https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/:76:13)at Anonymous function (https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/:57:46)...

Comment: Can you try it Excel online? it also works as expected in my side

Comment: It works online! I'll keep trying to get that to work on desktop since it's my preferred option.

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot of the error and your excel version?

Comment: Just edited the main post. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please confirm whether your gist was updated? I cannot repro this issue anymore

Answer (score 0):

I can repro this issue now, this gist works in Mac and Online, but Excel Windows desktop has an issue. A bug (4127946) was created to track this issue. Our team is working on the investigation.

Comment: Thank you very much Raymond! I'm eager to have that working on my office to keep using script lab.

Comment: Have you update the gist, it seems I cannot repro this issue anymore.

Comment: Hi! The gist is from a Youtube video, so I can't answer that, sorry. Here you are a copy of the original gist: https://gist.github.com/alfonsofuentesquintas/cb5afd2294a147b06bf21d762d086f29

Comment: Can you repro with your gist in your side?

Comment: just have a try on the original gist, it works as expected. can you verify in your side? https://gist.github.com/alfonsofuentesquintas/cb5afd2294a147b06bf21d762d086f29

Comment: Yes, I still have the same issue in Excel Desktop, but I haven't change anything on the  Office Installation so that's expected.